# pass text from python to delphi dll

Tags: python-3.x, delphi, dll

How can I pass text from python3 to a dll written in delphi.

Delphi dll code

```
library pascal_test;
{$MODE Delphi}
function test(s : string) : integer; stdcall;
  begin
    writeln(s);
  end;
exports test;
end.
```

Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.pascal_test
print(lib.test('mystring'))
```

Comment: It's not written in Delphi. That's freepascal code. And you can't call that function because it uses a native `string` type. Change the argument to `PWideChar` or `PAnsiChar` depending on your chosen text encoding. Use `windll` rather than `cdll` because the function is `stdcall`. Set `windll.pascal_test.argtypes` to `[c_wcharp]` or `[c_charp]` depending on which encoding you opt for.

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan. Now the first character of "mystring" is printed. How do I pass  the full string

Comment: That implies that the caller sends UTF16 wide text and the recipient expects 8 bit encoding. Make sure your encodings match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, that I found to work:

Free pascal code

```
library pascal_test;
{$MODE Delphi}
  function test(s : PAnsiChar   ) : integer; stdcall;
  var
    t: string;
  begin
    t:=s;
    writeln(t);
    test:=0;
  end;
  exports test;
end.
```

Python code

```
from ctypes import *
lib = windll.pascal_test
lib.argtypes = [c_char_p]
print(lib.test(b'teststring'))
```

**Update**

Updated to use windll and stdcall

Comment: Ok, what should be changed. I tried a lot of combinations that did not work and finally this worked.

Comment: If you use `cdll` then your Pascal function needs to be marked as `cdecl`. If you use `windll` then your Pascal function needs to be marked as `stdcall`. Please don't program by trial and error. It doesn't work. The code in this answer is broken and only appears to work by chance. You need to understand interop, calling conventions, binary ABI etc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the errors. I have updated the answer to use windll and stdcall